# как при нажатии на кнопку бесконечно добавлять текст в Label(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label

Есть код:

```
from tkinter import *

# commands

def add_one():
    label1.config(text=message.get())

# head
root = Tk()
root.title("MMR")
root.geometry("250x400")
# nameLabel
name_label = Label(text="MMR:")
name_label.pack(side=TOP)
# txt
message = StringVar()
message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message)
message_entry.pack(side=TOP)

# btn
btn = Button(text="Update", command=add_one)
btn.pack(side=TOP)

# LABEL
label1 = Label(text="TEST", fg="#eee", bg="#333", width=250, height=400)
label1.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Если я ввожу в Entry и нажимаю кнопку, то введеный текст появляется в Label, но после повторного нажатия он изменяется на новый. 
Как сделать так чтобы текст добавлялся бессконечно в поле Label

Answer (score 4):

```
def add_one():
    label1["text"] += message.get()
```

Comment: После того как оставил ответ предполагал, что label1["text"] позволит и поменять значение, но забыл проверить это :)

Answer (score 3):

Измените так метод:

```
def add_one():
    text = label1["text"] + message.get()
    label1.config(text=text)
```