Показ текста по кнопке tkinter
Есть заранее заготовленный текст в виде переменной w. Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку этот текст выводился в Label?

А что вы уже пробовали сделать?

Ничего. Я без понятия как это сделать. Очевидно через функцию, но дальше я не знаю

Хорошо, а что уже есть?

У меня есть кнопка, Label, и текст в виде переменной

Так и добавили бы этот код в вопрос, а там  уже на основе этого - спрашивали бы как довести до ума. А вообще нужно учиться пользоваться поиском по ресурсу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863995/как-при-нажатии-на-кнопку-бесконечно-добавлять-текст-в-labeltkinter?rq=1

@ДмитрийГончарёнок, Изменение текста в Label

Простите, я не пользовался этим сайтом раньше. Спасибо

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
